# React native app won't build after installing react-native-vector icons

Tags: xcode, typescript, react-native

I've been trying to add `react-native-vector-icons` in my project recently using `react-native 0.63.4`. However when I build the project I got this from the terminal when I ran this terminal command `npx react-native run-ios` and the error/warning are as follows:

```
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/json.h:48:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/dynamic.h:796:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/dynamic-inl.h:22:
/Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/Conv.h:1266:44: warning: possible misuse of comma operator here [-Wcomma]
      [&](Tgt res) { return void(out = res), src; });
                                           ^
/Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/Conv.h:1266:29: note: cast expression to void to silence warning
      [&](Tgt res) { return void(out = res), src; });
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                            static_cast<void>( )
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperClient.cpp:8:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperClient.h:14:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperConnectionImpl.h:12:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperConnection.h:10:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/json.h:48:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/dynamic.h:796:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/dynamic-inl.h:23:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/Format.h:30:
/Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/String.h:73:18: warning: '\a' command does not have a valid word argument [-Wdocumentation]
 * \' \" \? \\ \a \b \f \n \r \t \v
               ~~^
/Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/String.h:73:21: warning: '\b' command does not have a valid word argument [-Wdocumentation]
 * \' \" \? \\ \a \b \f \n \r \t \v
                  ~~^
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperClient.cpp:8:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperClient.h:16:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperInitConfig.h:10:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/io/async/EventBase.h:46:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/io/async/AsyncTimeout.h:19:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/io/async/EventBaseBackendBase.h:21:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/io/async/EventUtil.h:21:
In file included from /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Flipper-Folly/folly/portability/Event.h:24:
/Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Headers/Public/libevent/event.h:44:10: fatal error: 'event2/event-config.h' file not found
#include <event2/event-config.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-Glog' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.4, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper-PeerTalk' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'boost-for-react-native' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'GCDWebServer' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target'/Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/CMakeLists.txt' of type 'text' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: no rule to process file '/Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper-RSocket/rsocket/benchmarks/README.md' of type 'net.daringfireball.markdown' for architecture 'x86_64' (in target 'Flipper-RSocket' from project 'Pods')
warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.4.99. (in target 'Flipper' from project 'Pods')

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    CompileC /Users/newuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/numbers-dwsoqoxfvlhqaegkspswqexutfzn/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/FlipperRSocketResponder.o /Users/newuser/workspace/programming/mobile/numbers/ios/Pods/Flipper/xplat/Flipper/FlipperRSocketResponder.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
```

I further tried to build with Xcode but I got this from it:

```
/Users/newuser/workspace/libevent/event.h:44:10: 'event2/event-config.h' file not found
```

I've tried `pod install` & `pod update` still the app won't build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution please for this link: [Solution](https://exerror.com/event2-event-config-h-file-not-found/)

Comment: The link in your answer is broken

Answer (score 0):

i ran into this,
you should troubleshoot your installation common problem is not having fonts in infoplist
check your infoplist
it needs to have

```
<key>UIAppFonts</key>
<array>
    <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
    <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
    <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Feather.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
    <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
    <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
    <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
    <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
    <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
    <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
    <string>icomoon.ttf</string>
</array>
```

if not run

```
react-native link react-native-vector-icons
```

another solution is to use legacy build system from

```
workspace settings -> build system -> legacy build system
```

another thing is

> If you are using use_frameworks! in your Podfile you instead need to
> dynamically load the icon font by doing Icon.loadFont() when
> boostrapping your application.

Comment: still not working and now seeing an error from `flipper`

Comment: did you download any custom pods outside of react native

Comment: I found a solution, there's no need to change to `legacy build system`